# Display data of array in vue js view

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, vue.js

This is my function of controller

```
   $teams= ChallengeTeam::where('challenge_id', '=', $id) 
                ->join('users AS leader', 'challenge_teams.team_leader_id', '=', 'leader.id')
                ->join('users AS captain', 'challenge_teams.team_captain_id', '=', 'captain.id')
                ->select(
                    'leader.first_name AS leader_first_name',
                    'leader.last_name  AS leader_last_name',
                    'challenge_teams.id',
                    'challenge_teams.team_name',
                    'captain.first_name AS captain_first_name',
                    'captain.last_name AS captain_last_name',
                    'challenge_teams.unique_id',
                    'challenge_teams.avatar'
                )
        ->get();

        foreach($teams as $team) {
            $t = ChallengeTeam::find($team->id);
            $members = $t->members()
                    ->join('users', 'challenge_team_members.user_id', 'users.id')
                    ->select(
                        'users.first_name',
                        'users.last_name',
                    )
                    ->get();

            $team['members'] = $members;
        }

        return response()->json([
            'teams' => $teams,
        ], 200);
```

It gives me result as >> `Object { teams: Getter & Setter, … }`

If i click further on object , ```

1. **ob**: Object { value: {…}, dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }
   ​
2. teams: (6) […

and further in teams

```
0: Object { leader_first_name: Getter & Setter, leader_last_name: Getter & Setter, id: Getter & Setter, … }
​​
1: Object { leader_first_name: Getter & Setter, leader_last_name: Getter & Setter, id: Getter & Setter, … }
​​
2: Object { leader_first_name: Getter & Setter, leader_last_name: Getter & Setter, id: Getter & Setter, … }
​​
3: Object { leader_first_name: Getter & Setter, leader_last_name: Getter & Setter, id: Getter & Setter, … }
​​
4: Object { leader_first_name: Getter & Setter, leader_last_name: Getter & Setter, id: Getter & Setter, … }
​​
5: Object { leader_first_name: Getter & Setter, leader_last_name: Getter & Setter, id: Getter & Setter, … }
```

and this is my function to get it

```
 loadTeams(challengeId) {
                axios.get("/api/auth/admin/challenge/" + challengeId + "/teams") 
                .then(function (response) {
                this.teams = response.data;
                console.log(this.teams)
                }.bind(this)); 
            },
```

but whenever i am trying to display it , its not coming

```
   <tr v-for="team in teams" :key="team.id">
                                <td class="font-w600">{{team.team_name}}</td>
                                <td class="">{{team.leader_first_name }} {{team.leader_last_name }}</td>
                                <td class="">{{team.captain_first_name}} {{team.captain_last_name}}</td>
                                <td class="">{{ team.unique_id}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No there is no error message !! Infact If i check console, data is being fetched in>> Object { teams: Getter & Setter, … } . But i am not able to display it in my component view.

Comment: if i set <tr v-for="team in teams" :key="team[0].id">  <td class="font-w600">{{team[0].team_name}}</td> </tr>                                                                        **It displays result as my first team details** but how should i do if i want to display table of all teams !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tbody v-for="team in teams" :key="team.id">                  
          <tr v-for="t in team" :key="t.id">
               <td>
                   <img :src="getAvatar(t.avatar)" class="img-thumbnail" width="75" alt="no image found" />
               </td> 
               <td class="font-w600">{{t.team_name}}</td>
               <td class="">{{t.leader_first_name }} {{t.leader_last_name }}</td>
               <td class="">{{t.captain_first_name}} {{t.captain_last_name }}</td>
               <td class="">{{ t.unique_id}}</td>
          </tr>
</tbody>
```

This was the thing required and it solved my issue !!